# Blockchain flow in food industry

Tags: blockchain

I am trying to learn blockchain by doing small projects. I was able to complete a small project in blockchain for cryptocurrency using c#. Now, I am trying to understand the flow of a blockchain in food industry. I understand that there is basic flow from the farmer > producer > retailer > consumer.

In cryptocurrency chain there were transactions and it keeps getting added from everywhere. And miners do the job of creating blocks. But for the food, I am unable to get the flow... Lets say we have a farmer and he registers his products with all farm info etc. Does he create a block containing the product info ? Or the product info is simply broadcasted to all nodes as mere products ? In crypto currency, the transactions are broadcasted to a mempool and miners do the job next. What is the flow inside for food industry ? I need some guidance in programming perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution gathered from leads provided by Mikko and Gokul. I hope I am going in the right direction.

Just like in the cryptocurrency the food  chain may have something called Items list (like transaction list). The Items list would have the ItemId, Farm, Producer, Retailer, Consumer info. Each being a class of its own with its own class members. 
The farm will register the items and push them in the chain in the ItemsPool (Like the mempool). So for example the farm will push the item with itemid, farm info etc.

The itemspool could have several other items from several other farms. Each record identified uniquely by its ItemId. And each item is verified in any prescribed way before being pushed into the chain. At any specific condition a block of (items) can be generated by the miners.

Then when the producer receives the goods (physically) the producer will begin the digitization of the items. So a new record of item is pushed by the producer with Producer info + itemId. 
ItemId being the main tag for tracing the product in the chain.

Before being supplied to the chain, the item is verified against the previous record from the farm. And the next record is added by the Retailer and finally the consumer. And then at any point of time, the consumer can trace back the product in the chain.

Comment: I read over that quickly and it sounds like it can work.

Answer (score 0):

We have a project that has done a live pilot with most expensive food supply chain - sea food:

https://fishcoin.co/

I suggest you study their materials (papers, videos) to understand how they do it.

You are mixing two different concepts here: Application (supply chain) and infastructure (blockchain and how blocks are generated). They are independent of each other. Although one could technically answer to this, it is better to first have a better separation of concerns and understand how existing projects operate.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of food processing industry use cases such as 'farm to fork', Blockchain can function as the product provenance and supplychain track and trace platform. The focus should be on tracking the flow of goods and services through the value chain and providing a single source of truth for all the stakeholders. When you design a Blockchain for this requirement, the governance model, transaction model, consensus model, validations, authorisations etc. should be defined separately. Verification of quality and quantity of food items, associated metadata, associated service functions etc. are also important.